# I don't understand a parameter in this class (Swift)

Tags: swift, algorithm, parameters, tree, closures

```
public class BinaryNode<Element> {
    public var value: Element 
    public var leftChild: BinaryNode? 
    public var rightChild: BinaryNode? 
    public init(value: Element) { self.value = value }

    public func traverseInOrder(visit: (Element) -> Void) {
        leftChild?.traverseInOrder(visit: visit)

        visit(value) // <--- this code.

        rightChild?.traverseInOrder(visit: visit)

    }
}

var tree: BinaryNode<Int> {

    let zero = BinaryNode(value: 0)
    let one = BinaryNode(value: 1)
    let five = BinaryNode(value: 5)
    let seven = BinaryNode(value: 7)
    let eight = BinaryNode(value: 8)
    let nine = BinaryNode(value: 9)

    seven.leftChild = one
    one.leftChild = zero
    one.rightChild = five
    seven.rightChild = nine
    nine.leftChild = eight

    return seven // root node
}

// for print it
tree.traverseInOrder {
    print($0)
}
// result:
// 0
// 1
// 5
// 7
// 8
// 9
```

I'm studying a tree data structure and the algorithm that walks it. 
I found some code on the web, but it is quite strange to me that I am using a parameter as a closure in the function.

> visit(value)

How does this closure from the parameter work in this code sample?

I tried searching to understand it, but I don't even know what keyword to use when searching it.

Thanks.

Comment: `visit: (Element) -> Void` is a closure declaration (I might be technically wrong, but if the shoe fits), acts like a function.  In this case, it's a call back, so when `traverseInOrder` will call this closure and pass it the `value` of the `Node` ... kind of a sweet idea actually

Comment: Thanks to answer, MadProgrammer. But can I ask one more thing? I still don't understand a mechanism how "visit(value)" can pass the value of Node. Thanks again.

Comment: Think of it just like a function, that you pass as a parameter to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Declaration**

```
visit: (Element) -> Void
```

In the above code `visit` is declared as a `closure` of type `(Element)->Void`. It'll accept a value of type `Element` (*generic type*) wherever called.

**2. Initialization**

Since `traverseInOrder(visit:)` accept a `closure`, so you pass one when calling this method.

This is how you initialize the `closure` generally,

```
tree.traverseInOrder { (value) in
    print(value)
}
```

The code below is the same thing as above, just a shorthand for it.

```
tree.traverseInOrder {
    print($0)
}
```

**3. Calling**

```
 visit(value)
```

That's how you call the `visit` `closure` by passing the relevant value in it.